# UITableViewCell: How do I update textLabel.text at fifth row?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I created and fulfilled UITableViewCell. I want to update textLabel.text at fifth row when I pressed UINavigationButton. How can I do this?

```
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [tableView_ dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"any-cell"];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"any-cell"] autorelease]; 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
cell.textLabel.text = leftString;
```

Comment: Show as some code. Is your UITableViewCell customized?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The direct way is,

```
NSIndexPath *fifthRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:fifthRow];
cell.textLabel.text = @"the updated text";
```

But, the better way is to update the *dataSource* and reload the *tableView* or just the row.

Comment: Updating label in cell directly may look nicer than reloading that cell via table's methods sometimes. But even if you do that - you **must** update data source anyway.

Comment: If a cell is updated directly without updating the dataSource and it is not visible at the time of updation then the updation won't reflect in the cell as the cell's are resused here.

Comment: Exactly, that's why you must always update data source. And then it is up to you how to update cell itself - either with table's reload methods or directly.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but I have a (somewhat) similar problem that I've highlighted in this thread below, wherein my button actions are changing the stored data, but are not being reflected on screen. Thanks in advance for any assistance:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27275027/uilabel-in-custom-uitableview-cell-not-updating-with-core-data-change/27275457#27275457

Answer (score 0):

You'll can tell the `UITableView` to refresh that row (with `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`) in the method that is handling the button edits.

Then have a special case in your `UITableViewDataSource` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

EDIT: I deleted this answer after seeing @EmptyStack's answer, which looked good to me.  Perhaps this answer will cover his suggestion of updating the DataSource?