# UILabel in custom UITableView cell not updating with Core Data change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm attempting to build a game scoring app that utilizes a custom table cell with player photos, names, buttons etc...  There are add/subtract buttons directly in the custom cell of the tableview that are hitting my save method, and it's storing it back in Core Data for that specific user.

The problem is with the on-screen score not updating and reflecting the change.  After the save action to Core Data is complete, I'm calling the **[self.tableView reloadData];**... nothing.  However, if I restart the app, then the change in score (for any of the players I've clicked on), appears.

Maybe I'm making this harder than it needs to be, either that, or I'm just not grasping the real problem.

Thoughts / comments?
Thanks a load in advance.
:-)

Sorry if this is overkill, but here is the majority of my implementation file:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self resetViews];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    [context setUndoManager:nil];
    _managedObjectContext = context;

    self.tableView.delegate = self;

    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}


-(void)resetViews {

    NSLog(@"\n\n\nresetViews()");

    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)setupFetchedResultsController {

    NSString *entityName = @"Players";
    NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:
                               [NSSortDescriptor
                                sortDescriptorWithKey:@"playerName"
                                ascending:YES
                                selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    _playerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:results];

    NSLog(@"_playerArray count: %i", [_playerArray count]);
    NSLog(@"\n");
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _playerArray.count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"playerCell";
    ScoringCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    Players *player_info = [_playerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSSet *score = player_info.scores;

    for (Scoring *perObj in score){
        cell.lblPlayerScore.text = [perObj.score stringValue];
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n score for %@: %@", player_info.playerName, perObj.score);
    }

    cell.lblPlayerName.text = player_info.playerName;
    cell.lblPlayerNickName.text = player_info.playerNickName;
    cell.btnIncreaseScore.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.btnDecreaseScore.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.imgPlayerPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tmp_playerImage"];

    return cell;
}


- (IBAction)increaseScore:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"PageContentViewController: increaseScore()");
    UIButton* btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    int selectedPlayerInt = btn.tag;
    //NSLog(@"Selected row is: %d",btn.tag);

    Players *player_info = [_playerArray objectAtIndex:selectedPlayerInt];
    [self updateRowScore:player_info:@"add"];
}

- (IBAction)decreaseScore:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"PageContentView: decreaseScore()");
    UIButton* btn=(UIButton*)sender;
    int selectedPlayerInt = btn.tag;
    //NSLog(@"Selected row is: %d",btn.tag);

    Players *player_info = [_playerArray objectAtIndex:selectedPlayerInt];
    [self updateRowScore:player_info:@"subtract"];
}

-(void)updateRowScore: (Players *)player_info :(NSString *)modifier {

    NSLog(@"\n\nupdateRowScore()");
    NSLog(@"Update score (%@) for: %@\n", modifier, player_info.playerName);

    NSArray *scoreDataArray;

    if ([self playerScoreCount:player_info] == 0) {

        // NEW score... we've never scored before.
        Scoring *scoring_data = [NSEntityDescription
                                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Scoring"
                                 inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

        //Since this is the first score, always set it to 1
        scoring_data.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        scoring_data.holeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_pageIndex];
        scoring_data.scoredBy = player_info;

    } else {

        //Update existing player score..
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *BEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Scoring" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:BEntity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                                  predicateWithFormat:@"(scoredBy = %@)", [player_info objectID]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        scoreDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:results];

        Scoring *score_update = [scoreDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
        int currentScore = [score_update.score intValue];
        NSLog(@"current score: %d", currentScore);

        if ([modifier  isEqual: @"add"]) {
            currentScore++;
        } else {

            // Don't allow negative scores.
            if (currentScore >= 1) {
                currentScore--;
            } else {
                currentScore = 0;
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"NEW score: %d", currentScore);
        score_update.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentScore];
    }


    // write to database
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    [self resetViews];
}
```

### [image]

---

**UPDATE:**
Thanks for the tip bbarnhart... I had read through that post before and had used that for a basis from which I had started. Decided to take it a step further and refactor a chunk of code using more of the Ray Wenderlich example.

I've seen some improvements to what's being recorded, and reported back through the NSLog's... but the view just still is not changing.

The action is increasing the score, and then I'm resetting the cell using `[self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:path];` In there... the method that is responsible for sending text to the display... the NSLog is showing `2014-12-04 22:40:40.199 appName[7153:150248] Score for Tim: 4` when the display still only shows 3.

I know this is some stupid rookie move... I'm just doing something dead wrong that I can't figure out.  Here's a snippet of the amended code.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Players"
                                   inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                              initWithKey:@"playerName" ascending:YES];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                        managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext
                                        sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                        cacheName:@"Root"];

    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    _playerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:results];
    NSLog(@"_playerArray count: %i", [_playerArray count]);

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {       
    id  sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"playerCell";
    ScoringCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[ScoringCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                   reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(ScoringCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Players *player_info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSSet *scoreSet = player_info.scores;

    NSString *cell_score;   
    for (Scoring *scoreObj in scoreSet) {
        cell_score = [scoreObj.score stringValue];
    }

    NSLog(@"Score for %@: %@", player_info.playerName, cell_score);

    if (cell_score != nil) {
        cell.lblPlayerScore.text = cell_score;
    }

    cell.lblPlayerName.text = player_info.playerName;
    cell.lblPlayerNickName.text = player_info.playerNickName;
    cell.btnIncreaseScore.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.btnDecreaseScore.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell.imgPlayerPhoto.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo_playerb"];

    [self resetViews];
    NSLog(@"\n");
}

- (IBAction)increaseScore:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"PageContentViewController: increaseScore()");
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    int selectedPlayerInt = senderButton.tag;
    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:senderButton.tag inSection:0];

    Players *player_info = [_playerArray objectAtIndex:selectedPlayerInt];
    [self updateRowScore:player_info:@"add":selectedPlayerInt:path];
}

-(void)updateRowScore:(Players *)player_info :(NSString *)modifier :(int)selectedPlayerInt :(NSIndexPath *)path  {

    NSArray *scoreDataArray;
    if ([self playerScoreCount:player_info] == 0) {

        // NEW score... we've never scored before.
        Scoring *scoring_data = [NSEntityDescription
                                 insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Scoring"
                                 inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

        //Since this is the first score, always set it to 1
        scoring_data.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        scoring_data.holeNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:_pageIndex];
        scoring_data.scoredBy = player_info;

    } else {

        //Update existing player score..

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *BEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Scoring" 
                                  inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:BEntity];

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                                  predicateWithFormat:@"(scoredBy = %@)", [player_info objectID]];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        scoreDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:results];

        Scoring *score_update = [scoreDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
        int currentScore = [score_update.score intValue];
        NSLog(@"current score: %d", currentScore);

        if ([modifier  isEqual: @"add"]) {

            currentScore++;
        } else {

            // Don't allow negative scores.
            if (currentScore >= 1) {
                currentScore--;
            } else {
                currentScore = 0;
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"NEW score: %d", currentScore);
        score_update.score = [NSNumber numberWithInt:currentScore];
    }


    // write to database
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"playerCell";
    ScoringCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:path]; 
    [self resetViews];  
}
```

### ----------

**UPDATE:**
Been awhile since I've had a chance to revisit, and just noticed a new problem since enabling your tips.  When scrolling down or up in the list and pulling beyond the normal boundaries, the tableview data seems to overwrite the display for the row either above or below the current line.  Weird...  Not sure if this animated Gif will show up in Stack.  Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: **Note to self:** don't have `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` inside configureCell... Lots of loading strangeness will commence (see animated example above)  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason your table view is not updating dynamically is `NSFetchedResultsController` uses a delegate for notification when changes occur.  You'll need to set that delegate, `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self` and then add the delegate methods.

Here is a [link to an example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) for managing a `UITableView` with a `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Update

Implement these `NSFetchResultsController` delegate methods to allow your table to be dynamically updated.

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
```

Generally, these methods contain boilerplate code for updating your table which you will also find in the link above.

Comment: Aside from my Edit/update above... I found something strange.  If I tap my add or delete buttons, it's still saving to Core Data, but not updating what I see on screen.   

However... if I pull the list down so "Tim's" score is temporarily out of view... when I let go and it springs back, the score on the view is updated.

Comment: When you added `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self` it caused the `NSFetchedResultsController` to observer changes to the underlying data.  You still need to make your `UITableView` dynamically reflect any changes.

Comment: Huh -- I thought that's what I was was doing by calling  [self.tableView reloadData].  I'll keep poking around a bit I guess.  Thanks for your help getting this far...  :-)

Comment: reloadData will reload all the data. You just want to update the cells that changed. That example with the delegate methods is what you want.

Comment: I'll dig through the Ray Wenderlich example further.  I've got those 3 methods added in with breakpoints in each of them but they don't seem to be getting hit.  Shouldn't have anything to do with the fact that my view is a standard UIViewController with an embedded UITableView.... Eh... I'll keep looking.

Comment: Oh my God... I'm such an idiot.  Countless, and I mean COUNTLESS times I've looked at my code, the example from Ray Wenderlich, your assistance above. Sure, I needed to tweak some parts of my code, but do you know what the real problem was?!?!  I didn't have the referencing outlet hooked up to my main tableView! So when I was trying to call reloadData or even reloadRowsAtIndexPaths it was doing nothing, because it had nothing to do it to!  Oye.  Thanks for all your help bbarnhart, it came in very handy! :-)

Comment: That's a gotcha too.  Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Disregard my last edit above with the animated gif example --  I had `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` inside of my configureCell method.  So yeah, it was firing and reloading... A LOT.  Doh.  Happy holidays.  :-)